# How to collide constrained bodies

Tags: bulletphysics

Whenever I connect two bodies with *btGeneric6DofConstraint*, bullet doesn't detect collisions between them anymore and lets them freely penetrate into each other. How do I force it to detect collisions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify if you want the two objects to collide with a flag when you call to addConstraint() to the world.